# Creating timestamps and dates in java

Tags: java, sql, date, timestamp

There are many java classes that handle time (date, calander..etc) and there are even more references and tutorials online which makes it all very confusing and I don't know which class to use when.

Can anyone give me straightforward statements to do the following:

1. Create an instance of a timestamp to keep track of transactions on a database
2. Create an object that holds today's date in DD/MM/YY format (or anything similar)
3. Create an object that holds ANY given date in DD/MM/YY format (or anything similar)

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Ans1**
You can get current date using.

```
Date date = new Date();
```

In SQL you can mark the date field to update to current time automatically.

**Ans2**
[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) allows a variety of date formats. An example usage is:

```
Date d = new Date(secondsSunceEpoch);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String time = df.format(d);
```

**Ans3**
Use [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) method from SimpleDateFormat for any string would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {

            DateFormat todaysDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
            Date date = new Date();

            //2. datestring hold your today's object in DD/MM/YY format 
            String datestring = todaysDateFormat.format(date);
            System.out.println("datestring "+datestring);


            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
            java.util.Date parsedDate;
            parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(datestring);
            Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());

            //1.  Create an instance of a timestamp to keep track of transactions on a database
            System.out.println(timestamp);  // Use this time stamp as today's date foramt

            // 3.Create an object that holds ANY given date in DD/MM/YY format 
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy");
            java.util.Date parsedDate3;
            parsedDate3 = dateFormat.parse("30/12/14");  // any given date
            String anyDatestring = todaysDateFormat.format(date);
            // it will hold any date string

        }catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct but outdated. They use troublesome old legacy classes. Instead use java.time classes.

## 1

> Create an instance of a timestamp to keep track of transactions on a database

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

In Java 8 the current moment is captured with milliseconds resolution. In Java 9, up to nanosecond resolution. In both versions of Java, the `Instant` class is capable of holding a nanosecond value.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

In JDBC 4.2 and later, exchange with your database via the `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject`. If your driver cannot do so, convert to a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
```

## 2

> Create an object that holds today's date in DD/MM/YY format (or anything similar)

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in Paris France is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

To generate a String you can specify a formatting pattern, or just let [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) localize. A [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) determines (a) the human language used for translation, and (b) the cultural norms for deciding issues like capitalization, abbreviation, and punctuation.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizeDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.UK );
String output = today.format( f );
```

## 3

> Create an object that holds ANY given date in DD/MM/YY format (or anything similar)

Do not conflate a date-time object with a String representation of that date-time value. The object can parse or generate such strings but is separate and distinct from the string.

So we already saw the solution above: a `LocalDate` object holds the date-only value. When needed for presentation to the user, generate a String to represent the value.

By the way, calling [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) gets you a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String output = localDate.toString();
```

The java.time classes follow the immutable object pattern. So you do not modify an existing object to alter part of its value. Instead you create a new object with parts of its value based on the original object.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );
```